# snap - no refresh.retain configuration

Tags: snap

Trying the following command :

```
sudo snap get system refresh.retain
```

I get that message.

```
$ sudo snap get system refresh.retain
[sudo] Mot de passe de jm : 
erreur : snap "core" has no "refresh.retain" configuration option
```

Do I have to set refresh.retain, using "$ sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2"
or is it not important, and I keep the system that way. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your output is normal: `refresh.retain` is already using the default value of 2 on all supported releases of Ubuntu (except Ubuntu Core, which is 3). You need make no changes.

Currently, you cannot query snapd to discover the default values that are used.

So if your snapd queries look like this...

```
$ sudo snap get system
Key      Value
refresh  {...}
seed     {...}
system   {...}
```

...or...

```
$ sudo snap get system refresh
Key  Value
$
```

...then you are using the default values. Snapd does not tell you what those default values are. Snapd only tells you what you have changed.

You must [consult the documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date) to learn the default values.

Snapd is Open Source, and if anybody wants to contribute code to cure that papercut, their contribution will be welcome.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought there was something wrong.

Comment: @Arvernes And you are not mistaken. It told you that there was an error and you had to come here to find out what it means.